# looking for a hadith - "buildings of mecca will reach the mountain tops"

Tags: hadith, source-identification

looking for a hadith - "you will see the building of mecca reach the mountain tops"

in arabic

"itha ra'aitun mecca bu'ijat katha'ima, wa ya-tasawa bunyahnuha ru'usa jibaliha, faqad athalati sa'atu"

Possibly imam a-Suyuti.

Comment: "itha ra'aitun mecca bu'ijat katha'ima” 
“If you see mecca with holes in it’s mountains” - refer to tunnels used by pedestrians and vehicles during hajj to the masjid. 
“wa ya-tasawa bunyanuha ru'usa jibaliha”
“And when it’s buildings reach (or surpass) it’s mountain tops” - The clock tower, and buildings in mecca now built.
“faqad athalati sa'atu"
“Then the hour has cast it’s shadow” - meaning it’s shadow has reached us, the difference being between, looking at an object from a distance and watching it approach us and looking at an object whose shadow touches us.

Answer (score 4):

Abdullah ibn Umru ([عبد الله بن عمرو](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/showalam.php?ids=13)) said:

> فإذا رأيت مكة قد بعجت كظائم ورأيت البناء يعلو رءوس الجبال فاعلم أن
>   الأمر قد أظلك
>
> So if you see in Makkah that channels have been dug and the buildings
>   reach the mountain tops then know that the hour has cast it's shadow
>   over you

This hadith can be found in [Al Musannaf (المصنف) of (ابن أبي شيبة)](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=10&ID=5095&idfrom=5572&idto=5622&bookid=10&startno=5) see (hadith 124) for it's entirety.  It is not attributed to the Prophet (Peace and blessings be upon him) but is Mawqoof (موقوف) at Abdullah ibn Umru, and it's sanad is ok (لا بأس به).